# How to implement two structs that can access each other?

Tags: c++, syntax, struct, dependencies, forward-declaration

The code what I have written:

```
    struct A;
    struct B;
    struct A
    {
        int v;
        int f(B b)
        {
            return b.v;
        }
    };

    struct B
    {
        int v;
        int f(A a)
        {
            return a.v;
        }
    };
```

The compile message:

```
|In member function 'int A::f(B)':|
11|error: 'b' has incomplete type|
7|error: forward declaration of 'struct B'|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

I know, why that code is not correct, but I don't know how to implement two structs that can access each other. Is there any elegant way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I re-tagged this as C++, since it's not C.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to keep the exact same signature of your member functions, you have to postpone the definition of the member functions until both class definitions have been seen

```
    // forward declarations
    struct A;
    struct B;

    struct A
    {
        int v;
        int f(B b); // works thanks to forward declaration
    };

    struct B
    {
        int v;
        int f(A a);
    };

    int A::f(B b) { return b.v; } // full class definition of B has been seen
    int B::f(A a) { return a.v; } // full class definition of A has been seen
```

You might also use `const&` function arguments (better performance for when `A` and `B` are large), but even then you have to postpone the function definitions until both class definitions have been seen.

Comment: And I would just point out that something like `const A &a` exists.

Comment: You are the only one that claims pointer is not necessary and I test your code, works! You are a expert on C++!

Comment: @Vyktor tnx, I added a sentence to that effect.

Comment: @Sayakiss Pointers are only necessary if you want something like `struct A { B* b; };` and `struct B { A* a; };`.